# Difference between "checkout revision" and "checkout files" in Git

Tags: git, git-checkout, mplab-5.45

I am using Mplab X IDE ver 5.45 user graphical interface for for versioning in Git.
When I want to checkout a particular commit the menu gives the option "Checkout revision" or "Checkout files". Could someone please explain which is the difference? (I am not expert in Git).

Moreover: is there any kind of CLI console in Mplab to give git commands and read git messages?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: I don't know what Mplab is, and I do not recommend letting a GUI get between you and Git. But the difference between a "revision" (commit) and a file is pretty clear; this is just the overloaded nature of `git checkout`. See the docs, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout, which actually start by pointing out this double nature of `checkout`. Personally I literally never use `git checkout` for _anything_ any more, exactly because it is so overloaded (and dangerous); I use `git switch` and `git restore` to do those different jobs.

Comment: Anyway, "When I want to checkout a particular commit" means "Checkout revision" is what you want; a revision is a commit. Stay away from "Checkout files" unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The [MPLAB® X Integrated Development Environment (IDE)](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-x-ide) [thread](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m922784.aspx) suggests:

- **checkout files** restores files at the current revision (equivalent to [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore))
- **checkout revision** switches to a given project revision (equivalent to [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))

However, that same thread mentions (in 2017, so it might have changed):

> Probably the single biggest problem I have found so far is that if you use "Check out" in MPLAB it does not currently "flush" and reload the configuration files.
>
> The changes made by Check-out can even hang the IDE.
> When winding back to earlier versions this makes it retain bits of newer version configurations such as source file names that don't exist yet.
>
> It seems as if you must close the project and check out with an external `git` such as `git_gui` to get configurations to reload properly.
> Checking out lesser revisions that don't change configuration will work fine, though.